# Removing unnecessary duplication

Tags: javascript, duplicates, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm trying to remove these playerVars from the default settings because it's unnecessary duplication.

```
    start: 0,
    end: 999999,
    loop: true,
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/461/

```
  function addVideo(video, settings) {
      const defaultSettings = {
              width: settings.width || 640,
              height: settings.height || 390,
              videoId: video.dataset.id,
              playerVars: {
                  start: 0,
                  end: 999999,
                  loop: true,
```

**Would there be a way where I would only add them if they are needed?**

As was done in this example:

https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/432/

**Doing this would remove a lot of unnecessary duplication.**

```
 loadPlayer({
        target: ".jacketc",
        width: 600,
        height: 338,
        playerVars: {
            start: 200,
            end: 205,
            loop: true
        }
    });
```

**It doesn’t need to be stated in both the top:**

```
  function addVideo(video, settings) {
 const defaultSettings = {
         width: settings.width || 640,
         height: settings.height || 390,
         videoId: video.dataset.id,
         playerVars: {
             start: 0,
             end: 999999,
             loop: true
```

**And also at the bottom:**

```
loadPlayer({
    target: ".jacketc",
    width: 600,
    height: 338,
    playerVars: {
        start: 200,
        end: 205,
        loop: true
    }
});
```

These should only be added to loadPlayer if they are needed.
    They shouldn’t be required to be at the top in the default settings.

```
start: 0,
end: 999999,
loop: true,
```

**These should only be the default settings:**

```
     autoplay: 1,
     controls: 1,
     showinfo: 1,
     rel: 0,
     iv_load_policy: 3,
     cc_load_policy: 0,
     fs: 0,
     disablekb: 1
 };
```

These would only be added to loadPlayer if they are needed.
If they are not needed they don’t need to appear in the javascript.

```
    start: 0,
    end: 999999,
    loop: true,
```

**How would I be able to implement this adjustment to the code?**

https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/453/

Where these playerVars aren’t needed in the default settings.
They only get added to loadPlayer if they are needed.

```
        start: 200,
        end: 205,
        loop: true,
```

**That’s exactly how it works in this other code.**

https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/465/

**How would I be able to implement that in the new, updated code?**

https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/453/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your question but from my understanding you want to set `playerVars` optionally in function `addVideo()` but do not want to define `playerVars` as input variable? maybe you can try this

```
["start", "end", "loop"].forEach(function (a) {
    if (settings[a]) {
        defaultSettings.playerVars[a] = settings[a];
    }
});
// or
for (let a of ["start", "end", "loop"]) {
  if (settings[a]) defaultSettings.playerVars[a] = settings[a];
}
// or
let optional = ["start", "end", "loop"];
for (let i = 0; i < optional.length; i++) {
  if (settings[optional[i]]) {
    defaultSettings.playerVars[optional[i]] = settings[optional[i]];
  }
}
```

complete code

```
function addVideo(video, settings) {
  const defaultSettings = {
    width: settings.width || 640,
    height: settings.height || 390,
    videoId: video.dataset.id,
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
      controls: 1,
      showinfo: 1,
      rel: 0,
      iv_load_policy: 3,
      cc_load_policy: 0,
      fs: 0,
      disablekb: 1
    },
    events: {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady,
      "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
    }
  };
  ["start", "end", "loop"].forEach(function(a) {
      if (settings[a]) defaultSettings.playerVars[a] = settings[a];
  });
  const updatedSettings = combineSettings(defaultSettings, settings);
  console.log(updatedSettings)
  players.push(new YT.Player(video, updatedSettings));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If I was using 'for loop' instead of .forEach, how would that part be written?

Comment: Thank you very much, greatly appreciated.

Comment: The 2nd.) one should be: for (let a of / or for (var a of. Correct? https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/492/

Comment: There's a jslint error in the forEach code: https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/486/ "Unexpected statement '=' in expression position." / settings[a] && (defaultSettings.playerVars[a] = settings[a]) / How would that be fixed?

Comment: jslint is too strict for minification, usually I use [JSHint](https://jshint.com/) for code quality check and since your last comment I have change the foreach.

Comment: Expected '{' and instead saw 'defaultSettings'. This line:  if (settings[a]) defaultSettings.playerVars[a] = settings[a]; https://jsfiddle.net/hzyrfkwb/504/ How would that be fixed?

Comment: after `if` It need to be wrapped in `{}`, 4 space indent.